# How to retrain the inception model (windows)?

Tags: tensorflow, cmd

I am trying to follow along with the steps for tensorflow for poets 2 and every time I try to retain the inception model with new datasets I get this error. 
This is the [article](https://medium.com/datadriveninvestor/building-an-image-classifier-using-tensorflow-3ac9ccc92e7c) I was trying to follow along.

I have reinstalled tensorflow twice.

> File
>   "D:\Files\downloades\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 18, in swig_import_helper    fp, pathname, description =
>   imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', [dirname(**file**)]) 
>   File "D:\Files\downloades\lib\imp.py", line 296, in find_module
>   raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name) ImportError: No
>   module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> Traceback (most recent call last):  File
>   "D:\Files\downloades\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py",
>   line 58, in     from
>   tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *  File
>   "D:\Files\downloades\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 28, in     _pywrap_tensorflow_internal =
>   swig_import_helper()  File
>   "D:\Files\downloades\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 20, in swig_import_helper    import _pywrap_tensorflow_internal
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> Traceback (most recent call last):  File
>   "D:\Files\downloades\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
>   "**main**", mod_spec)  File "D:\Files\downloades\lib\runpy.py", line
>   85, in _run_code    exec(code, run_globals)  File
>   "C:\Users\Rishi\Desktop\tensorflow-for-poets-2\scripts\retrain.py",
>   line 109, in     import tensorflow as tf  File
>   "D:\Files\downloades\lib\site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py", line
>   24, in     from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  #
>   pylint: disable=unused-import  File
>   "D:\Files\downloades\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python__init__.py",
>   line 49, in     from tensorflow.python import
>   pywrap_tensorflow  File
>   "D:\Files\downloades\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py",
>   line 74, in     raise ImportError(msg) ImportError: Traceback
>   (most recent call last):  File
>   "D:\Files\downloades\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 18, in swig_import_helper    fp, pathname, description =
>   imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', [dirname(**file**)]) 
>   File "D:\Files\downloades\lib\imp.py", line 296, in find_module
>   raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name) ImportError: No
>   module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> Traceback (most recent call last):  File
>   "D:\Files\downloades\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py",
>   line 58, in     from
>   tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *  File
>   "D:\Files\downloades\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 28, in     _pywrap_tensorflow_internal =
>   swig_import_helper()  File
>   "D:\Files\downloades\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 20, in swig_import_helper    import _pywrap_tensorflow_internal
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

For some common reasons and solutions, I have included the entire stack trace
above this error message. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Thanks, Emma for editing my post, really appreciate that.

Comment: Can you show us the code that you run? And which version of tensorflow did  you install? Please read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and consider the recommendations there. Otherwise it might be difficult for us to help you.

Comment: I was trying to follow this article https://medium.com/datadriveninvestor/building-an-image-classifier-using-tensorflow-3ac9ccc92e7c